# Documentation for Interface Builder sections

Tags: ios, xcode, uiview, interface-builder

Where can I find documentation for properties shown in Interface Builder?

For example, here is a screenshot of the Property Inspector when I have a `UIView` selected in my StoryBoard. I'd like to know what the "Installed" checkbox controls but hovering over it doesn't present any type of tooltip. `UIView` does not seem to contain a "installed" method/property. So, I have no idea what this is supposed to do.

Again, this is just an example... there are many things in the Property Inspector that I can't find documentation for.

[image]

Comment: Most of them are described in the attributes inspector reference: https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/UIKitUICatalog/View.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40012857-CH8-SW1

Comment: The installed checkbox controls whether the view is in the view hierarchy or not for a specific size class.

Comment: A lot of Interface Builder features are poorly documented. There's a "feedback" link on the page that dan shared with us, where you can indicated which features are inadequately documented. Alternatively, you can post a "Feature" request at http://bugreport.apple.com. There's no guarantee that those will be incorporated, but Apple does consider these as they release subsequent Xcode versions.

Comment: FYI, the "installed" checkbox is discussed about 30-31 minutes into WWDC 2016 [Making Apps Adaptive, Part 1](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2016/222/).